# Automated Gmail Logins

Tags: python, selenium, gmail, google-signin, chrome-web-driver

Gmail has stopped the use of automated browser sign in. **Is there any way to bypass it?**

I am using selenium with a chrome driver along in python.

This is the error:

> You are trying to sign in from a browser or app that doesn't allow us
>   to keep your account secure. Try using a different browser. Learn more

Comment: Consider using the [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) instead

Comment: I can log in with the latest `ChromeDriver` by having the driver go through the same steps as I would normally go through (enter username, enter password, wait for mailbox to load)

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: currently Google has more restricted rules for applications which want to access Gmail. In Google setttings should be option to allow access gmail by untrusted applications. OR you may have to generate unique password for every application which you use (especially python scripts)

Comment: [Allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/)

Comment: [How to Create an App Password for Gmail](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/)